# Java database display randomly

Tags: java

```
private void Label_GenerateMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try{
        String sql = "select from Account ORDER BY RAND()";
        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){
            TextField_Username.setText(rs.getString("EMAIL"));
            TextField_Password.setText(rs.getString("PASSWORD"));
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Cannot generate.");
    }
}
```

This code keep catching the error and i cant figure out why. im gettign error java.lang.NullPointerException. Please help

Comment: Dump the exception stack trace and add it to your question.

Comment: use `System.out.println("Cannot generate." + e.getMessage());` to see real error

Comment: What is the error? Could you paste your stack trace. There can be null pointer exception on PreparedStatement, ResultSet, ...

Comment: You wrote `select from`

Comment: eror: Cannot generate. java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: use `String sql = "select * from Account ORDER BY RAND()";` as per @AmineZaine comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NVM GUYS I FIGURED IT OUT. I DIDNT RUN MY CONNECTION FUNCTION. srry for the troubles.

Comment: Still, there are a number of other issues with your code, including the fact that your SQL statement is broken. See comments and additional answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String sql = "select EMAIL,PASSWORD from Account ORDER BY RAND()";
        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){
            TextField_Username.setText(rs.getString("EMAIL"));
            TextField_Password.setText(rs.getString("PASSWORD"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, your SQL statement is incorrect. Instead of

```
"select from Account ORDER BY RAND()"
```

it should be

```
"select Email, Password from Account ORDER BY RAND()"
```

When doing a select, you need to specify either the columns being selected, or use * to specify all tables. Production SQL code should never do a `SELECT *`, though; you should only specify which columns you're actually using to avoid leaking data and wasting time.

Also, I hope that `Password` column has its data encrypted...